# What is the right c# syntax in javascript quotes

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

What is a corect way of adding if/else c# statement within javascript code?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var test = "<%=if(btn1.Text=="a") btn1.Text else "N/A" %>";
        </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use single quotes in javascript:

```
var test = '<%=if(btn1.Text=="a") btn1.Text else "N/A" %>';
```

Comment: You can also escape the double quotes as an alternative so it would be
var test = "<%=if(btn1.Text==\"a\") btn1.Text else \"N/A\" %>";

Comment: This works fine, is there a way of making this work in separate JS file, not from aspx page?

Comment: Not without alot of hacking around or a custom solution. You could create a hidden field in files importing the script that the script grabs the value of or set the value as a property of the document via JavaScript within the files importing the script.

Comment: You could store the value of btn1.Text in a `<input id="btn1Value" type="hidden"/>`, and then get the value of that input from your external script file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague:
However, from context I am assuming you are talking about using an if else relationship and printing the results in a View within a JavaScript block using ASP.NET which in this case a ternary operator would do what you are looking for - not 100% sure you need to change the quotes like the above answer recommends, but that may also be needed:

```
var test = "<%= btn1.Text=="a"? btn1.Text: "N/A" %>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of the two previous answers and use single quotes and the ternary operator

`var test = '<% btn1.Text == "a" ? btn1.Text : "N/A" %>'`